# Twitter Follow button issue in different browsers

Tags: twitter, plugins, cross-browser, compatibility

I am working on social plugins integration on my local site and i m trying to add twitter follow button onto it...but it is behaving differently in different browsers..Normally its works in the page...i have a slider inside which it is having this code...thats where it showing its case...i dont know why the follow button is rendering differently in different browsers...

the code i used to render the follow button,

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/Test" class="twitter-follow-button"
                  data-show-count="false" data-size="medium"></a>
```

and the script here,

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Similar codes i tried,

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/Test" class="twitter-follow-button"
                  data-show-count="false" data-size="medium">Follow @Test</a>
```

And this one too,

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/Test" class="twitter-follow-button"
                  data-show-count="false" data-size="medium">Follow</a>
```

I have tested this code with the following browsers,

**1.Firefox
2.Opera
3.Chrome
4.Safari**

1&2 works properly but 3&4 it not working properly...

1&2 its shows **Follow @Test**

3&4 is showing only **Follow**

Whats the problem?Why the **@Test** is left out in 3&4 browsers....or does my code need some changes...or is it the browser problem...

Comment: i dont think we need a css for this script to run..see here...https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button ...

Comment: The script is presumably importing some CSS in order to display your button? The text could be wrapping, try `Follow&nbsp;@Test` or setting the `data-width` attribute?